# How to install Ruby on Rails with mysql and get it working, a step by step guide?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Some time ago I managed to get RoR working on Windows XP.
I've been trying to get it working on Windows 7 for 2 days but there's just no way, there's always a problem, one that google can't answer, no matter what I try.

Can someone give me a guide or something to get it working on Windows 7 or XP ? Even Ubuntu but I'd rather not go through that maze again.

I figure I'm going to install Windows XP on a virtual machine and start from there.

I need RoR and mysql - what versions, where do I download them from and what steps do I take ?

On a side note, how do you install mysql2 (version < 0.3) on rails 3.0.7 ? Because it automatically tries something over 0.3 which doesn't work on rails 3.0.7 and if I try the gemfile bundle trick with 0.2.7 I don't know how to specify configuration options and of course it doesn't work if I don't give it the location of mysql lib and include directories.

Also I tried using rails 3.1 beta and everything goes smoothly until I start the server and the website never loads on localhost:3000.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is basically what I do to install on Windows 7:

- Download and install latest mysql from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/
- Install Ruby http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ (check the box to update PATH)
- Install Ruby Devkit http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ (for example extract to C:\DevKit)
- Setup Devkit

  cd [MY_DEVKIT_INSTALL_DIR]

  ruby dk.rb init

  ruby dk.rb install
- Copy libmysql.dll from your mysql/bin install to C:\Ruby192\bin

  gem install rails

  gem install mysql2 -v 0.2.6

  rails new my_test_app -d mysql

Comment: Ah, there it goes. Seems like I had to use the -v 0.2.6 and change the version in the gemfile. Thank you very much.

Comment: After numerous nightmarish hours trying to do the same, I figured I'd write down how I got it working 8)

Comment: @ReubenMallaby, where would I find "mysql/bin" in this context?  I've looked under Program Files\MySQL, used Windows 7's search tool to attempt to locate libmysql.dll without success.  MySQL is installed and working on my system (phpMyAdmin can interact with it).

Answer (score 3):

To setup Rails on windows, just download and click:

http://railsinstaller.org/

Comment: This uses 1.8.7 so the installation will be slower than a real one.

Comment: ... I do use Ruby 1.8.7 Enterprise Edition in production which just suits perfectly my needs. 1.9.2 is not a must have, at all

Comment: Excuse me if I'm wrong, but I don't think that link is for EE.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://rubyinstaller.org/ it should get you up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I like Aptana Studio 3 for developping with RoR on Windows 7. The book "Agile Web Development with Rails" is also full of good advices.

Here are the steps I followed:

1- Installing Ruby via [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/)

2- Install MySQL (follow @Reuben Mallaby instructions)

3- Install Rails

With the Built-in Terminal, make dev' easy. You should take a look: [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3)