# ruby on rails 3.2.16 scaffolding method implement

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

Does rails 3.2.16  version  have scaffoldind method? if it has then what to do to       implement it ?

How do I edit `database.yml` file to use mysql as adapter ?

Answer (score 0):

Add to Gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

Then in your database.yml for each env respectively

```
development:
 adapter: mysql2
 encoding: utf8
 reconnect: false
 database: db_name
 pool: 5
 username: root
 password: root
 timeout: 5000
```

for scaffolding new rails project with mysql database:

```
rails new -d mysql
```

for more details run

```
rails new -h
```

Comment: in bitnami ruby stack console i run the command: rails new project_name -d mysql . but in the end console shows : an error occured installing mysql2 and bundler can not continue. make sure that 'gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.14' ' succeeds before bundling.

Comment: Seems you don't have required dependencies for mysql client libraries. What kind of operating system are you using? e.g Linux/MacOs?

Comment: do you have mysql installed ? looks like no. this should help http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ also this link should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996834/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-mysql-and-get-it-working-a-step-by-step-guide